# mlpack library error: undefined symbol architecture arm64

Tags: c++, ios

I have created iOS static library using mlpack C++ library using all dependencies and dependencies are armadillo, boost C++ library.

I have used to make the iOS static library mlpack c++, armadillo ,ensmallen and boost library.

Below are mlpack library link: https://github.com/mlpack/mlpack

I am using iOS static library into iOS project and call iOS static library C++ method function then found arm64 undefined symbol errors.

iOS static library always build successful.
My iOS static library project structure snapshots:
[iOS static library project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHVqI.jpg)

When use iOS static library into iOS project found arm64 errors. Showing the boost serialization errors.

Below are error snapshots:
[Using iOS static library showing errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxaMc.jpg)

```
typeinfo for boost::serialization::typeid_system::extended_type_info_typeid_0
Undefined symbol: boost::serialization::typeid_system::extended_type_info_typeid_0::is_less_than(boost::serialization::extended_type_info const&) const
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::detail::archive_serializer_map<boost::archive::binary_oarchive>::erase(boost::archive::detail::basic_serializer const*)
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::detail::archive_serializer_map<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::erase(boost::archive::detail::basic_serializer const*)
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::detail::archive_serializer_map<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::insert(boost::archive::detail::basic_serializer const*)
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::detail::basic_oserializer::~basic_oserializer()
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::detail::archive_serializer_map<boost::archive::xml_oarchive>::erase(boost::archive::detail::basic_serializer const*)
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::detail::archive_serializer_map<boost::archive::xml_oarchive>::insert(boost::archive::detail::basic_serializer const*)
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::detail::basic_pointer_oserializer::~basic_pointer_oserializer()
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive::save_pointer(void const*, boost::archive::detail::basic_pointer_oserializer const*)
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive::register_basic_serializer(boost::archive::detail::basic_oserializer const&)
Undefined symbol: typeinfo for boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::basic_binary_oarchive<boost::archive::binary_oarchive>::init()
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::basic_xml_oarchive<boost::archive::xml_oarchive>::end_preamble()
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::xml_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::xml_oarchive>::~xml_oarchive_impl()
Undefined symbol: boost::serialization::typeid_system::extended_type_info_typeid_0::extended_type_info_typeid_0(char const*)
Undefined symbol: boost::serialization::typeid_system::extended_type_info_typeid_0::type_register(std::type_info const&)
Undefined symbol: boost::serialization::extended_type_info::key_register() const
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::detail::basic_oserializer::basic_oserializer(boost::serialization::extended_type_info const&)
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::basic_binary_oprimitive<boost::archive::binary_oarchive, char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::save(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::basic_binary_oprimitive<boost::archive::binary_oarchive, char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::init()
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::detail::archive_serializer_map<boost::archive::binary_oarchive>::insert(boost::archive::detail::basic_serializer const*)
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::basic_binary_oprimitive<boost::archive::binary_oarchive, char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::basic_binary_oprimitive(std::__1::basic_streambuf<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool)
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::basic_binary_oprimitive<boost::archive::binary_oarchive, char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >::~basic_binary_oprimitive()
Undefined symbol: boost::serialization::typeid_system::extended_type_info_typeid_0::is_equal(boost::serialization::extended_type_info const&) const
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::save(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception const&)
Undefined symbol: typeinfo for boost::archive::detail::basic_oserializer
Undefined symbol: mlpack::math::randGen
Undefined symbol: typeinfo for boost::archive::archive_exception
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::basic_text_oarchive<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::newtoken()
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::basic_text_oarchive<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::init()
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive::end_preamble()
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::archive_exception::~archive_exception()
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::basic_xml_oarchive<boost::archive::xml_oarchive>::save_end(char const*)
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::basic_text_oprimitive<std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> > >::~basic_text_oprimitive()
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::basic_xml_oarchive<boost::archive::xml_oarchive>::save_override(boost::archive::tracking_type const&)
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::basic_xml_oarchive<boost::archive::xml_oarchive>::save_override(boost::archive::class_id_optional_type const&)
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::basic_xml_oarchive<boost::archive::xml_oarchive>::save_override(boost::archive::class_name_type const&)
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::archive_exception::archive_exception(boost::archive::archive_exception::exception_code, char const*, char const*)
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::text_oarchive>::text_oarchive_impl(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, unsigned int)
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::basic_xml_oarchive<boost::archive::xml_oarchive>::save_override(boost::archive::class_id_type const&)
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive::save_object(void const*, boost::archive::detail::basic_oserializer const&)
Undefined symbol: typeinfo for boost::archive::detail::basic_pointer_oserializer
Undefined symbol: boost::serialization::typeid_system::extended_type_info_typeid_0::type_unregister()
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::basic_xml_oarchive<boost::archive::xml_oarchive>::save_override(boost::archive::class_id_reference_type const&)
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::basic_xml_oarchive<boost::archive::xml_oarchive>::save_override(boost::archive::object_reference_type const&)
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::basic_xml_oarchive<boost::archive::xml_oarchive>::save_override(boost::archive::version_type const&)
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::basic_xml_oarchive<boost::archive::xml_oarchive>::save_start(char const*)
Undefined symbol: boost::serialization::extended_type_info::key_unregister() const
Undefined symbol: mlpack::math::randUniformDist
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::basic_xml_oarchive<boost::archive::xml_oarchive>::save_override(boost::archive::object_id_type const&)
Undefined symbol: mlpack::Log::Fatal
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive::~basic_oarchive()
Undefined symbol: mlpack::Log::Warn
Undefined symbol: mlpack::util::PrefixedOutStream::operator<<(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >& (*)(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&))
Undefined symbol: boost::serialization::typeid_system::extended_type_info_typeid_0::~extended_type_info_typeid_0()
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::basic_xml_oarchive<boost::archive::xml_oarchive>::init()
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::xml_oarchive_impl<boost::archive::xml_oarchive>::xml_oarchive_impl(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, unsigned int)
Undefined symbol: mlpack::Timer::Start(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::detail::basic_oarchive::basic_oarchive(unsigned int)
Undefined symbol: boost::archive::detail::basic_pointer_oserializer::basic_pointer_oserializer(boost::serialization::extended_type_info const&)
Undefined symbol: mlpack::Timer::Stop(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)
Undefined symbol: mlpack::util::PrefixedOutStream::operator<<(char const*)
```

**Need some suggestions or any idea to fix the issues. Any type of help more appreciate able.**